# Need to create collection of keys with multiple values (Laravel 7.x)

Tags: arrays, laravel, collections, eloquent

My first post here. I tried to search for an answer, but no luck, so here we go

Generally I cannot share with you with the exact code I'm working on :( 
so here's the example one:

```
$collection = collect(['country' => 'Germany', 'city' => 'Berlin', 'month' => 'April']);
dd($collection);
//"country" => "Germany"
//"city" => "Berlin"
//"month" => "April"
$array1 = ['France', 'Paris', 'May'];
$array2 = ['Spain', 'Madrid', 'June'];
```

My question is - how to "add" those arrays (minding array1 and array2 order) so I end up with something like this?

```
dd($newCollection);
//output:
//"country" => ["Germany", "France", "Spain"]
//"city" => ["Berlin", "Paris", "Madrid"]
//"month" => ["April", "May", "June"]
```

#### OR

If there's a way to get all records from database and make one of the rows a key and a selection of them as values

Example

```
$users = User::get();
//this table has columns "full_name", "e-mail", "job", "birth_date", "city" and "password"
$collection = <<???>> //make column "full_name" as key and columns "e-mail", "job", "password" as values
dd($collection);
//output:
//"John Doe" => ["johndoe@mail.com", "Janitor", "topsecret"]
//"Jane Doe" => ["janedoe@mail.com", "teacher", "sercretpassword"]
```

Lifetime gratitude in advance for an answer... I've read Laravel's documentation many times and could not find a solution

Comment: This seems a little pointless. If you're getting all your `$users` via `User::get()`, then each `$user` (given the loop `foreach($users as $user)`) will contain all that information, `$user->full_name`, `$user->email`, `$user->job`, `$user->password`. Unless you need that specific format `'full_name' => ['email', 'job', 'password']` it's extra work to get what you already have.

Comment: Also, sidenote, please ensure `password` column in your database is not plaintext. If you're storing an un-hashed version of `password` in your `users` table, that's a huge security flaw.

Comment: It's just an example, all passwords are hashed ;)
And thanks for your answer, I think I have an idea how to tackle this!

Comment: Excellent :) I hoped as much, just a confirmation. And if you come up with a solution, feel free to post it as a self-answer; it might help someone else in the future. Cheers!

Comment: Why not "full_name" = $users->pluck('full_name') ; and so on....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### I've got this

The solution for me looks like this:

```
$users = User::get();
//this table has columns "id", "full_name", "e-mail", "job", "birth_date", "city" and "password"

//I don't want to use all columns here
foreach($users as $user=>$value){
    $full_name = $value->full_name;
    $e-mail = $value->e-mail;
    $job = $value->job;
    $password -> $value->password;
    $endresult[] = [$full_name, $e-mail, $job, $password];
}

$collection = collect($users->keyBy('id')->pluck('id'))->combine($endresult);
dd($collection);
//output:
// 1 => ["John Doe", "johndoe@mail.com", "Janitor", "topsecret"]
// 2 => ["Jane Doe", "janedoe@mail.com", "teacher", "sercretpassword"]
```

It looks terrible, but works like a charm. I needed to format this like so because in my project there are many foreign keys and I need to pagify my results, so to make it the easiest way possible I need to combine all values to one key (just like a row in csv) rather than call for every value in view

### thank you for your support

Answer (score 0):

You've technically asked two questions here. One where you merge a set of values into a key-value collection, and another where you simply limit the values from a set of key-value collections and key by the ID.

Given that you're really looking for an answer to the second question, by way of your answer, here's a cleaner way of doing it:

```php
User::select('id', 'full_name', 'email', 'job', 'password')
  ->get()
  ->keyBy('id')
  ->map(function($user) {
    return collect($user)->except('id');
  });
```